# Me.Controls for timers declared at runtime

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

due to some VS problems I have started declaring timers at runtime such as

```
Private WithEvents _TmrAll As New Timer
```

Now when I shutdown my app, I want to disable all timers.
I used to make it like so:

```
Private Sub pDisableAllTimers()

    For Each T As Control In Me.Controls
        Dim sName As String = T.GetType.Name
        If sName = "Timer" Then
            T.Enabled = False
        End If
    Next T
End Sub
```

But for the timers declared at runtime, this doesn't seem to work.
At least they're not found in the loop.

Thank you.

Comment: They don't belong to the controls collection, you can either address each control by name or add them to the controls collection or add them to a different collection

Comment: Timers are Components, so they dont go in the Controls collection. You have the reference to the one you created `_TmrAll` use that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this at runtime, you'll need to create the `components` container (If needed) and add your timer(s).  For more information check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069391/whats-the-purpose-of-the-components-icontainer-generated-by-the-winforms-design)

```
   If components Is Nothing Then
        components = New System.ComponentModel.Container()
   End If       
   components.Add(_TmrAll)
```

and then code `pDisableAllTimers` as follows:

```
Private Sub pDisableAllTimers()

    For Each T As Component In components.Components
        Dim sName As String = T.GetType.Name
        If sName = "Timer" Then
            CType(T, Timer).Enabled = False
        End If
    Next T

End Sub
```